# how to download en_core_web_sm in orange3?

Tags: nlp, spacy, orange

I want to use spacy inside Python script in Orange3 tool, but I get this error Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm' for using nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm"). I wonder how I can install this model in orange3?. Btw, I am using Orange3 as individual tool , not inside Anaconda jupyter notebook

Error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  File "", line 2, in  File "C:\Users\saif\AppData\Local\Orange\lib\site-packages\spacy__init__.py", line 30, in load return util.load_model(name, **overrides) File "C:\Users\saif\AppData\Local\Orange\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 169, in load_model raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name)) OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory. >>>

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error message did you get? The command to download that model is `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`, though I'd have to look into it further if there's Orange3-specific procedure.

Comment: Dear I tried this command but in Orange tool there is only Addon by name. which gives what typed as argument to pip install or conda. Do you how I can run the command in the tool? Btw, I m not using the Orange3 in Anconda , using it as a software

Comment: The error is line 169, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
>>>

Comment: Can you update your question to show the relevant code and the error message in its entirety?

Comment: How did you install Orange3? I'm looking to see how we can install the model to the installation of Python that it's using.

Comment: I installed it like a software just clicking next

Comment: Can you run these two lines in your Orange3 environment and tell me what it says? `import sys; print(sys.executable)`

Answer (score 2):

It appears that spaCy wants you to download their models using their command line interface, however if you're working in a development environment where all you can do is write scripts and run them (which I assume is the case regarding Orange3), you can import the function that spaCy uses internally to download and install models and call that.

```
from spacy.cli.download import download
download('en_core_web_sm')
```